# How to change proxy pass on apache server?

Tags: apache, proxypass

I would like to change the rules of proxy pass on apache server. Where is the configuration file? Can anybody give me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
/etc/httpd/conf.d/*.conf
google
```

Comment: Hello @Garrappachc With you help I found it at /etc/apache2/httpd.conf on my server. thanks!